# ASP classic db question

Tags: database, asp-classic

I am trying to execute a query like "show tables".  But I don't know the column names that will be returned by the query.  I've tried using something like

```
RS.Fields(1).Name
```

to show me the names but that doesn't seem to work.  Any suggestions?  Here is the full code:

```
   Response.Buffer = true

    Dim oConn, oRs
    Dim qry, connectstr, i

    i = 1
    connectstr = "Driver={MySQL ODBC 3.51 Driver};SERVER=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx;DATABASE=;UID=;PWD="

    Set oConn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    oConn.Open connectstr

    qry = "show tables"
    Set oRS = oConn.Execute(qry)

    while not oRS.EOF
        Response.Write("<td><b>" & oRS.Fields(i).Name  & "</b></td>")
        oRS.movenext
        i = i + 1
    wend


    Set oRs = nothing
    Set oConn = nothing
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
For I=0 to oRS.Fields.Count - 1
   Response.Write("<td><b>" & oRS.Fields(I).Name  & "</b></td>")
Next
```

Answer (score 2):

If you just want thie field names...

```
For Each fldF In objRec.Fields
    Response.Write fldF.Name
    Response.Write "<br />"
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your database user for this query has access to the database definition (structure). But you should denied the access to your web users for security (SQL injection).

Comment: This does not answer the question that was asked here.